# WebBrowser не открывает некоторые сайты

Tags: c#, webbrowser, ie11

Некоторые сайты не открываются с помощью контрола webbrowser. Проверил версию webbrowser свойством version, версия полностью совпадает с установленным IE на компе. Установленный на компе IE 11 версии открывает все те сайты, которые я не могу открыть с помощью webbrowser в программе.  Можно ли как-нибудь решить проблему или нужно использовать что-то другое?

перехожу стандартным образом

```
webBrowser.Navigate("example_link");
```

Добавил свойство для отключения ошибок js, не помогло

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorSuppresed = true;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы хоть ошибку что ли сказали, какая выдается. И что значит не открывает?

Comment: В прямом смысле не открывает, см. фото.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и этот способ. Решил с помощью этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call